# Segmentation fault in C program using array of char * and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

Silly little C program, but for the life of me I can't figure out why I keep getting a segmentation fault. I believe I'm allocating enough memory with malloc. Any help would be much appreciated. The code is supposed to read a day of the month and 'reminder' string from the user, and then reads these into data pointed to by the array reminders and allocated memory space with malloc.

```
/* Prints a one-month reminder list (dynamic string version) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_REMIND 50           /* maximum number of reminders */
#define MSG_LEN 60              /* maximum length of reminder message */

int read_line(char str[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    char *reminders[MAX_REMIND];
    char day_str[3], msg_str[MSG_LEN+1];
    int day, i, j, num_remind = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (num_remind == MAX_REMIND) {
            printf("-- no space left --\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter day and reminder: ");
        scanf("%2d", &day);
        if (day == 0) {
            break;
        } 
        sprintf(day_str, "%2d", day);
        read_line(msg_str, MSG_LEN);

        for (i = 0; i < num_remind; i++) {
            if (strcmp(day_str, reminders[i]) < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (j = num_remind; j > i; j--) {
            reminders[j] = reminders[j-1];
        }

        reminders[i] = malloc(2 + strlen(msg_str) + 10);
        if (reminders[i] = NULL) {
            printf("-- No Space Left --\n");
            break;
        }

        strcpy(reminders[i], day_str);
        strcat(reminders[i], msg_str);

        num_remind++;
    }

    printf("\nDay Reminder\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_remind; i++) {
        printf(" %s\n", reminders[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
int read_line(char str[], int n) {
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (i < n) {
            str[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to check `day`, except for zero. Suppose `day` is -10, or 100, or anything else that will result in more than two characters when printed. I know that those are not valid days, but **never trust input**.

Comment: "for the life of me I can't figure out why I keep getting a segmentation fault" -- It can be tough if all you're doing is staring at the code and you're not an experienced C programmer for whom `=` in an `if` statement jumps out. But any debugger or IDE will tell you that it segfaults in `strcpy` and the first argument to that call is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong:

```
if (reminders[i] = NULL) {
```

right:

```
if (reminders[i] == NULL) {
```

also, you are concatenating `day_str` & `msg_str`, so it's better to alloc:

```
reminders[i] = malloc(2 + strlen(msg_str) + strlen(day_str));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (reminders[i] = NULL) {
```

You set `reminders[i]` to `NULL` before you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

The dreaded assignment/comparison typo! This is a hint that your compiler warning levels are not set high enough or that you are ignoring the warnings.

```
// Should be '==' not '='
if (reminders[i] = NULL) {
    printf("-- No Space Left --\n");
    break;
}
```

Also, your `read_line` function is similar to [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html), which may simplify things.

Lastly, always validate your user input. Make sure `scanf` returns the number of items that you've asked for (usually 1 for simple one-item input). Otherwise, you're likely to venture into undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing assignment in if clause. It should be like this:

```
if (reminders[i] == NULL) {
    printf("-- No Space Left --\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks guys. I really need to read my own code more carefully.

Comment: @MassStrike What you really need is a decent compiler or lint that detects such errors. You also need some basic debugging skills ... the segfault happens in strcpy and it's trivial to note that its argument is 0.